# Raw SQL statement TypeOrm Migration issue

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

Does a regular INSERT INTO statement even work with TypeOrm? Tried formatting the string and quotes every which way, lost all patience.

```
await queryRunner.query('INSERT INTO "table"(column1,column2) VALUES ("Hi","Bye")');
```

> Error: column "Hi" does not exist.

ie: it tries using the 1st value as the column lookup.

I also tried

```
await queryRunner.query('INSERT INTO "table"(column1,column2) VALUES ($1,$2) --PARAMETERS["Hi", "Bye"]');
```

> Error: There is no parameter $1

Comment: See https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-insert/ for information on the syntax for inserting values into columns in Postgres. You are not formatting it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem come from the fact that you use double quotes for your string variable. As defined in [the postgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-STRINGS), a string is an arbitrary sequence of characters bounded by single quotes (`'`). And farther in the documentation you can find that the double quotes (`"`) are used to [defined identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) (such as table or column names)

Comment: Thanks but doubt that is it, did not make a difference, as i said tried playing around with all the quotes

Comment: You can doubt that this is it but the first error you describe is exactly it. PostgreSQL consider that `"Hi"` is an identifier of a column and not a string that should be used as an input variable, and so warn you that the column `"Hi"` does not exists.